# How to check if user.id is contained in an array of objects in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to check if a user (preferrably the id) is contained in an array of users, i am getting some issues when i try doing it this way

```
if (
  res.data.followers.includes(id=1)
){
    setIsFollow(true);
    console.log("user exists");
}
```

This is array

```
[
    {id: 1, username: 'destiny', email: 'desphixs@gmail.com'},
    {id: 2, username: 'flourish', email: 'flourish@gmail.com'},
]
```

i want to check if, for example, user with id 2 exists in the array, then conlog 'user exists';.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find?

Comment: Does this have to do anything with `reactjs`, `angular`, and `vue.js`?

Comment: @ZsoltMeszaros yes, its react that i am using

Comment: the question is not specifically related to any react specific functionality, nor do you admit that it has anything to do with vue or angular.  please don't abuse tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this. Here filter will return an array containing a single object that matches the id. Then you can check the length of the array, which should be equal to 1.

```
if(res.data.followers.filter(obj => obj.id === 1).length === 1) {
  // logic
}
```

Comment: `array#some` would be even more suited to this one. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some . This solution has the (maybe unintended) effect of failing on items that are in the list twice, since `.length` will `!== 1`